# Determine how many select elements are on form after removing one

Tags: jquery

All,
I'm removing some select options with jQuery using the following code:

```
$('#other_liked_vendors option[value=' + clicked_id + ']').remove();
length = $("#other_liked_vendors").val().length;
alert(length);
if($("#other_liked_vendors").val().length === 0){
    $("#view_other_liked_vendors").hide();
}
```

I'm basically trying to say if the last select element has been removed then I'd like to hide the div that the select element is in. Can anyone show me how to check this correctly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `.length` property of the jQuery object to see how many elements matched. So:

```
if ($('#other_liked_vendors option').length == 0) {
    // all options have been removed
}
```

You were trying to use the length of the `.val()`, which is the length of the string that is the currently selected option's value...

Answer (score 1):

`$("#other_liked_vendors").val().length` will give you the `length` of select elements selected value.

You should use this, which will find `option` elements with in the select element and check its `length` property.

```
if ($('#other_liked_vendors option').length == 0) {
    $("#view_other_liked_vendors").hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
if($('#other_liked_vendors option').size() == 0) {
......
```

OR better one

```
if($('#other_liked_vendors option').length == 0) {
......
```

Comment: size() is being deprecated in JQuery, better to stick to length